# Heroku Django Gunicorn Error H18 (Request Interrupted) errors

Tags: django, http, heroku, gunicorn

I'm using `Django` with `Gunicorn` on `heroku`. And I make `https` requests via post to my backend sending some files (which don't need to be stored), locally everything works fine.
But on `heroku` when I send small files (<13kbytes) it works, but for larger files I get

> Error H18 (Request Interrupted).

I couldn't understand the reason for the error, if it's from `heroku` itself, if it's from the body of the request to be large or from `gunicorn`.

What would be the best way to find out the possible cause of this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [clue](https://github.com/hunterloftis/heroku-node-errcodes/tree/master/h18#what-happens):

> An H18 signifies that the socket connected, some data was sent as part
> of a response by the app, but then the socket was destroyed without
> completing the response

You might have experienced one of the [limitations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits) on heroku if you're a free user. However, it's best to pinpoint the issue instead of speculating. What you can do is install the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-the-heroku-cli). Then, after you setup your account, send another large file on your backend. This will return the H18 error again. You can then trace the issue in your terminal with this:

```
$ heroku login
$ heroku logs --tail --app <your-heroku-app-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

For people in the future with the same problem,  me problem came of i dont wait all file be uploaded, locally works cause instantally files uploaded, but in server not is instantally. So to solve my problem i needed use await and promisses to wait the files and after that e call the backend.